# Moving a single MySql database to a separate physical disk

Tags: mysql, 17.04, apparmor

I am trying to move a single MySql database to another physical disk in my Ubuntu machine. I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

the external drive is mounted in /etc/fstab as follows (last line):

```
#zoneminder external drive
/path/to/new/location/zoneminder/images /var/cache/zoneminder/images none defaults,bind  0 2
/path/to/new/location/zoneminder/events /var/cache/zoneminder/events none defaults,bind 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a98ab607-15eb-4089-9197-7d26c3576cf9 /path/to/new/location ext4 x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I have tried the following steps:

stop mysql service:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Change owner of the mounted drive (I need to update the fstab entry to incorporate this,but one problem at a time!):

```
chown mysql:mysql /path/to/new/location
```

move to mysql folder

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
```

copy database (called zm) to the new location

```
sudo rsync -av zm /path/to/new/location/zm
```

rename old database

```
sudo mv zm zm.old
```

create symbolic link to the database we rsynced

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/new/location/zm
```

move to the new database location

```
cd /path/to/new/location
```

doing an ll at this point shows me that mysql is the owner of /path/to/new/location/zm

set file permissions

```
sudo chmod 700 zm
cd zm
sudo chmod 660 *
```

add the new location to apparmor

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

add

```
/path/to/new/location/ r,
/path/to/new/location/** rwk,
```

(re)start services

```
sudo service apparmor restart
sudo service mysql start
```

Log into mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

open the new database

```
use zm;
```

show tables

```
show tables;
```

and here I get an error:

```
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './zm/' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
```

I've also tried `chmod 777` and `chmod 777 *` in `/path/to/new/location` without success

Comment: What kind of filesystem and mount is `/path/to/new/location/` on and what is that directory's owner and permissions?

Comment: I've updated the question with my fstab entry

Comment: Any apparmor denials in `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: To @thomasrutter's question: who is the new directory's owner? I believe this to be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @richbl Changing /path/to/new/locations owner to mysql means I an now restart the service. However, I can't see the tables in the zm database now.....question updated

Comment: As a modification of Robie Basak's question; can you temporarily disable AppArmour just to check if mysqld works correctly with only file permissions set? (Maybe restart Mysqld after stopping AppAmour)

Comment: @stefan I stopped the apparmor service, restarted the mysql service but it still won't list the mysql tables...

Comment: As you have copied the database with `rsync -a` the files and directories should have the same owner, but please check if all the files in zm belong to mysql (e.g.`sudo find /path/to/new/location ! -user mysql`)

Comment: Can you create new databases in the new datadir?

Comment: @Stefan find /path/to/new/location/zm ! -user mysql returns nothing. I have not changed the datadir,, just created a symlink in the datadir to the new location. When I created a new database it goes in /var/lib/mysql

Comment: Before you changed directory ownership to mysql, who was owner? Also, when you `chown` are you making sure that the new location (`/path/to/new/location`) is completely owned by mysql (if `/path/to/new/location` has folders, run `chown -R`)?

Comment: Hi all, I have worked it out - see accepted answer. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I could not reconstruct your problem, as moving a database and linking to it from the datadir worked. Only when I activate SELinux (I am doing this on CentOS) do I get permission denied, Therefore I would suspect missing file permissions; you can not simply stop AppArmor you need: `sudo service apparmor teardown` , or `sudo aa-complain` (after start ;-). (A far cry would be file acls; check with mount ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixed it!**

The issue was the apparmor entry:

```
/path/to/new/location/ r,
/path/to/new/location/** rwk,
```

actually needed to be one directory up from what it was:

```
/path/to/new/ r,
/path/to/new/** rwk,
```

EDIT
Ubuntu 18.04 required me to change the owner of the symlink to mysql:

(in /var/lib/mysql:)

```
chown -h mysql:mysql zm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this variation:

```
1) first check in my.cnf [/etc/mysql/my.cnf] for database files destination.

2) let say that destination is in folder /var/lib/mysql/ and yours database name is "abccompany"

3) stop mysql database

4) move folder [var/lib/mysql/abccompany] to new destination (let say "/diskY")

5) make symbolic link:
     ln  -s  /diskY/abccompany   abccompany

6) start mysql database and everything should work just fine.
```